# Копирование текста при клике JavaScript

Tags: javascript, promise

```
  function copyClipboard(text) {
    return navigator.clipboard.writeText(text);
  }

  ipLink.addEventListener('click', copyClipboard(ipLink.textContent));
```

Вот такая функция для копирования текста при клике. Но есть одно НО. Когда я захожу на сайт, текст уже находится в буфере обмена, почему так происходит? как исправить?

Comment: Может вы просто в прошлый раз скопировали и забыли очистить буфер? :D Если нет, то скажите, это весь код?

Comment: Хаха)) к сожалению не в этом дело. Я даже копирую потом другой текст, вставляю и проверяю что да другой текст скопирован удачно. Обновляю страницу, тут же тот самый текст уже оказывается в буфере обмена... Касающийся копирования да это весь код

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`copyClipboard(ipLink.textContent)` - вы функцию вызываете сразу же, а не передаете в коллбэк, естественно сразу копироваться будет.

Оберните в функцию.

```
  function copyClipboard(text) {
    return navigator.clipboard.writeText(text);
  }

  ipLink.addEventListener('click', () => copyClipboard(ipLink.textContent));
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Вы правы, ну надо же! Благодарю!